# A Poisson Equation: how to solve it?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I wish to solve the Poisson Equation:$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=1,$$with $u(x,y)$vanishing on $r=a$.

I know that the final solution should be the sum of the homogenous part and the non-homogeneous part, which is $u(x,y)=u_1+u_2$, $u_1$ is the solution of $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0, u=0 \ on\ r=a,$$ and $u_2$ is the solution of $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=1, u=0 \ on\ r=a. $$ I have no trouble to find $u_1$, but how to solve $u_2$?

Any help, please.

Comment: for homogeneous part, I think it is zero, since the maximum principle....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the solution as two parts.

for the harmonic part,  we know $u_1$ is harmonic and vanishes at the boundary will give you the unique answer $u_1 = 0$

for the non-harmonic part, we can use Green's function method to get

$G(x-x_0,y-y_0)$, which satisfies

$\Delta G = \delta(x-x_0,y-y_0)$

$G(x-x_0,y-y_0)=0$ on boundary.

We know the fundamental solution is $\Gamma(x-x_0,y-y_0) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi}\ln((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2)$,

Then $G(x-x_0,y-y_0) = \Gamma(x-x_0,y-y_0)+ v(x,y,x_0,y_0)$

where $v$ satisfies

$\Delta v =0$

$v = f = -\Gamma(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ on boundary

Thus $v$ can be solved by using formula

$v = D\ast f$, where $D$ is Dirichlet kernel.

By integrating, I got $u_2 = \dfrac{1}{4}(x^2+y^2-a^2)$

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{1}{4}$ in $u_2$. But did you really solve this by using Green's representation? I got to the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{B(x;a)} \log\left( \frac{|x|}{a} |y-\frac{xa^2}{|x|^2}| \right)dy$ and couldn't get any further. Harald's answer gives the answer very quickly though.

Comment: @Stuart thanks you, I have corrected it. Actually I did it in complex way at very first. Since $\Delta = 4\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$, which will be very efficient for this kind of problems and can give an explicit construction of the solutions.

Comment: @Stuart And I think that integral is not hard to do, if you can use some symmetric property, like if you observe that $|x|$ fixed, then your answer will not change.

Answer (score 2):

How about starting with *any* solution $u_2$ of $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=1$, disregarding boundary conditions? You can think of solutions to that one without breaking a sweat. Now you have to find $u_1$ solving the homogeneous equation but with inhomogeneous boundary conditions, determined by the $u_2$ that you found in the first part.